# How can I convert list of numbers from select clause to int in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a sql statement in stored procedure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code,SOURCE, subtype_id FROM alarm_management.alarm_attribute WHERE id in (SELECT alarm_attribute FROM amisha_alarm_management.alarm_query WHERE id = '1'))
```

This subquery is returning numbers in string format i.e.

```
'{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}'
```

Due to this I am getting an error that ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = smallint[].How can I modify the query so that the subquery returns only numbers like

```
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
```

Comment: `select unnest('{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}'::int[]);`, though that will return a column of integer values. You will need to provide a more complete example of what you want to achieve to get an actual answer. Update your question with the new information.

Comment: I just have to remove the string format i.e. '{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}' and get the output in numbers i.e. 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18

Comment: It is not a string format it is an array format, see here [Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html). You can turn it into a string of numbers: `select array_to_string('{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18}'::int[], ','); 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18`. Again what you want to do with will determine whether this works. Not providing a complete example is not helping your cause.